# TFS is not reading all Junit xml Report(s) when a Build Fails?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, tfs

TFS is not reading all Junit xml Report(s) when a Build Fails?

For example when a build passes the TFS will read the JUNIT reports generated and in turn feed the information to the TFS dashboard, sometimes when exceptions (In Test cases) arise the reports and data contained within the reports will update fine.

I seem to be getting the odd build which will appear with the follwong message: 
[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with TFS 2017, the test project (https://1drv.ms/u/s!AresBGZVYryjhSfkTV44nc3wxmEn). What's the detail code of your test project and pom.xml? You may share a simple project on the OneDrive. Regarding the exception, you can do Exception testing (@Test(expected=... or add try catch block)(https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/exception-testing)

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved; it was not due to the JUnit reports generated (Even though im using TestNG), my methods contained failed assertions which in turn would also capture the webdriver locators used, in turn the locators sometimes contained characters were not readable to the TFS when the framework generated the JUnit reports and fed that information to the TFS.